# Mapping between child and root aggregate

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to create EF CodeFirst mappings for a legacy database.

Lets say that I got the following classes:

```
public class Subscriber
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public SubscriberAddress Address { get; set; }
}

public class SubscriberAddress
{
    //[...]
}
```

I want to configure a mapping between them. The tables looks like:

```
create table Subscriber
(
    Id uniqueidentifier primary key,
    -- [...]
)

create table SubscriberAddress
(
    SubscriberId uniqueidentifier,
    -- [...]
)
```

So the relation is in the `SubscriberAddress` table, but in the classes I would like the address to be a property in the `Subscriber` class.

I've tried with `WithRequiredPrincipal` and `WithRequiredDependent` but can't understand how to do the mapping since the FK is in the other table.

**Edit**

The `SubscriberAddress` do not have a property referencing `Subscriber` and `Subscriber.Address` is optional.

Comment: What sort of mapping are you looking for? 1 to 1 or 1 to many.
Also is address for the subscriber optional or required?

Comment: It's a one-to-one mapping and the SubscriberAddress is optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that its a 1 to 1 relationship and both are required this should work.

```
public class SubscriberContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Subscriber> Subscribers { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //modelBuilder.Entity<Subscriber>().HasRequired(x => x.Address).WithRequiredPrincipal(x => x.Subscriber);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Subscriber>().HasOptional(x => x.Address).WithRequired(x => x.Subscriber);
        modelBuilder.Entity<SubscriberAddress>().Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("SubscriberId");
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}

public class Subscriber
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual SubscriberAddress Address { get; set; }
}

public class SubscriberAddress
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Subscriber Subscriber { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @jgauffin updated my answer to reflect changes in question. The subscriber added to the subscriberaddress is just a navigation property on the poco class and doesn't in itself represent a column in the database. The above implementation maps the 'Id' property of the SubscriberAddress class to the underlying subscriberId on the table and also uses the same field as both PK on the table and FK to the Subscriber.